# Python file appears to be empty after a function

Tags: python

Code:

```
import os, csv

def menu():
    print("Welcome to da sporty ting" + "\n" + "Menu options: " + "\n")
    print("1 - Run the code")
    print("2 - Exit")
    menu_choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    while menu_choice not in (1, 2):
        menu_choice = int(input("Error, try again: "))

    if menu_choice == 1:
        finding_file()
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        exit()

def finding_file():
    print("\n")
    print("Text file options" + "\n")
    print("1 - testfile 1" + "\n" + "2 - testfile 2" + "\n" + "3 - Other")
    txt_menu_option = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    print("\n")
    while txt_menu_option not in (1, 2, 3):
        txt_menu_option = input(input("Error, try again: "))
    if txt_menu_option == 1:
        filename = "Test1_Votes.txt"
        pass
    elif txt_menu_option == 2:
        filename = "Test2_Votes.txt"
        pass
    elif txt_menu_option == 3:
        filename = str(input("Enter name of txt file (don't include .txt at he end) : "))
        filename = filename + ".txt"

        file_exists = os.path.exists(filename)

        if file_exists == False:
            print("File does not exist, returning to menu")
            menu()
        pass
    file_validity(filename)

def file_validity(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r+')  # opening file in read/write mode
    inv_lines_cnt = 0
    valid_list = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]  # sorted list of valid values
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0)  # truncating the initial file

    for l in lines:
        if sorted(map(int, l.split(','))) == valid_list:
            f.write(l + '\n')
        else:
            print(l + " is a invalid line")
            inv_lines_cnt += 1
    print("There were {} invalid line/lines.".format(inv_lines_cnt))
    calculate_quota(filename)

def calculate_quota(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r+')
    lines = f.readlines()
    print("Calculate quota " + str(lines))
    seats = 2
    line_count = 0
    for line in lines:
        line_count += 1
    quota = 0
    quota == int((line_count / (seats + 1)) + 1)
    print(quota)
    quota_required(quota, lines)

def quota_required(quota, lines):

    for line in lines:
        lines.rstrip(',')
        lines.rstrip('\n')
    print(lines)
    candidate_fp_votes = [0,0,0,0,0]
    for line in lines:
        for i in range(5):
            if line[i] == 1:
                print ("if working")
                candidate_fp_votes[i] += 1
                print (candidate_fp_votes)

    print (candidate_fp_votes)
```

Text file sample:

1,2,3,0,0

0,0,3,2,1

1,0,0,3,2

1,0,0,2,3

0,1,2,3,0

Currently I have a problem where after file_validity(), the text file just appears to have loaded up as empty as when I re-open the file in the next function, it prints lines as empty. file_validity() just deletes the file, and rewrites the valid votes. As you can see I have tried to find out where the trouble lies. I believe the truncate and seek functions seem to be causing some trouble but I am not sure if this is true. And if it were to be the case, how to fix it.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by using context-managers everywhere, that is a best-practice as far as working with files is concerned. You are using buffered file-handlers, but you never explicitly close your files. This is bad. Just use a context-manager. This should be your first debugging step. Otherwise, please try to narrow down the problem to a [mcve]. Don't just dump your whole code here, if most of it isn't relevant.

Comment: You need to explicitly close the file when you're done using it each time. Also, I believe that `f.truncate(0)` would have the effect of removing everything from the file?

Comment: I don't have a clue what a context manager is, as you can see in the code, I have tried to find the source of the error. I think it is the validity function but I do not know where.

Comment: @Pat Jones Please see my recent edit. How can I read the file and be able to access the lines after the truncate function. Will I need to open the file in another format or what?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see where you are coming from but I just put in the whole file so people know where each bit is coming from. If i was to answer a question, I would like to see where everything is coming from and how it works. But you seem to be the pro and people have different ways of doing things i guess.

Comment: @TIC-FLY if you have any aspirations of ever being a pro yourself, google is your first tool when people suggest something you're unfamiliar with.

Comment: I would remove `f.seek(0)` and `f.truncate(0)` and see what it does for you. The truncate( ) function has the effect of removing data from the file, and I'm assuming that you want to preserve what is in the file. So try removing it.

Comment: @TIC-FLY no, the issue is that you should be providing a [mcve], and not simply dumping your code and expecting people to debug it for you. Anyway, just google "context manager" and "with statement". But always open a file using `with open(<whatever) as myfile:`

Comment: @TIC-FLY as for context managers, I mean use the `with` statement to open your file. Again, I am almost certain that you will find that the issue relates to you not closing your file (and then re-opening it in another function!). You need to be careful when working with files. The best practice is to use a `with` statement. And generally, it is better to open it once, read form it, close it (the closing being handled by the `with` statement), and then open again and write to it (again, using a `with`) statement, rather than trying to do it all with `r+` mode.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I like your idea and i will try it out.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It seems to work, thanks!